# click a div in an .append with a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using an .append to populate a div-id and all that works fine, i even get the loop inside, however i would like to make an item clickable inside the loop and load a div that holds details of that item. This is what i got so far.

```
<div id="GameContainer"></div>

var gamesData; //A global variable to hold Ajax response.

$.ajax({
     type: 'Get',
     url: "http://"URL/" + GamesList,
     success: function (data) {

       gamesData = data; // add the Ajax data to the global variable

       var dynamic = "";

       for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

       dynamic += '<div id="' + data[i].id_game + '" class="TopContainerCel" onclick="GameDetails(' + data[i] + ')">'
               + '    <div class="TopContainerCelBackground">'
               + '          <img class="TopContainerCelImage" src="' + data[i].CoverImage + '" />'
               + '       </div>'
               + '    <div class="TopContainerCelName">' + data[i].Name + '</div>'
               + ' </div>'
             };

        $('#GameContainer').append(''
             + '<div class="TopContainerScroll">'
             + dynamic
             + '</div>');

      }
 })
```

// based on the solution of K K [extended with an array.find]

```
    added the global variable gamesData and filled it with the Ajax reponse

    $(document).on("click", ".TopContainerCel", function () {
        var elem = $(this);

        console.log(elem[0].id) // the actual id clicked is there
        console.log(gamesData) // all the data of the Ajax response is there

        GameID = elem[0].id;

        var gameData = gamesData[elem.data("id")]; // part that does not work
        var gameData = gamesData.find(x => x.id_game == GameID); // works!

       //gameData has the data
        console.log(gameData)

    });
```

So i found a diffent way of combining the two data together by using a find in the array. Is there a better way of doing this? If so why and what is the difference?

Comment: why not adding `data-id` attribute to `<div>` and onclick pass `this` to it, then you can use `$(this).data('id')`

Comment: it also did not work for me...

Comment: @El Alami Anas, this will give me just the id, i need to get the complete data set out.

Comment: It is the URL accepting an ID parameter after? If so, you could do another ajax call just item by item.

e.g. `url: "http://"URL/" + GamesList +"/"+gameID`

Comment: Store the data received from `AJAX` request in a global variable and Instead of passing the data to the function pass the id of the data as `GameDetails('+data[i].id_game+')`. then access the data in the function using the Id.

Comment: @Kamae, yes i thought of that as well. But i rather not make two calls. good idea tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something similar to this:

```
  var gamesData;//A global variable to hold Ajax response.
  $.ajax({
       type: 'Get',
       url: "http://URL/" + GamesList,
       success: function (data) {
       gamesData = data;

         var dynamic = "";

         for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

         dynamic += '<div id="' + data[i].id_game + '" data-id="'+data[id]+'" class="TopContainerCel">'
                 + '    <div class="TopContainerCelBackground">'
                 + '          <img class="TopContainerCelImage" src="' + data[i].CoverImage + '" />'
                 + '       </div>'
                 + '    <div class="TopContainerCelName">' + data[i].Name + '</div>'
                 + ' </div>'
               };

          $('#GameContainer').append(''
               + '<div class="TopContainerScroll">'
               + dynamic
               + '</div>');

        }
   })
  $(document).on("click",".TopContainerCel",function(){
    var elem = $(this);
    var gameData = gamesData[elem.data("id")];
    //gameData has your data
  });
```

**Note:** The approach here is to store ajax response in a variable. From your code, the response is an array. So, when you iterate over the items, get the index of the clicked item in any way you prefer and access the detail of game using the index from gamesData.

Comment: Hi K K, i triend your solution so far however up to the last part everything works, i get the games in the gamesData, i get the id# in the elem but i can't seem to get the connection between the two. It gives 'undefined'. This is what i get back from the elem: init [div#1371.TopContainerCel, context: div#1371.TopContainerCel]
0:div#1371.TopContainerCel
context:div#1371.TopContainerCel Length 1

Comment: i updated my question with your response and added the array.find cause i was not able to get the last part to work other wise

Answer (score 0):

you can add `data-id` to dynamic like : `<div data-id="'+data[i].id+'"`. 
then you can do :

```js
var games = {};

for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
       games[data[i].id_game] = data[i];
       dynamic += '<div id="' + data[i].id_game + '" class="TopContainerCel" onclick="GameDetails(' + data[i] + ')">'
               + '    <div class="TopContainerCelBackground">'
               + '          <img class="TopContainerCelImage" src="' + data[i].CoverImage + '" />'
               + '       </div>'
               + '    <div class="TopContainerCelName">' + data[i].Name + '</div>'
               + ' </div>'
};
```

```
$("#GameContainer").on('click','.TopContainerCel',function() {
  var $this = $(this);

  console.log(games[$this.data('id')])
  // code logic here
});
```

Comment: i just changed the last section, i need to get all the data out, not just the id :) if it would not work i would be able to use your suggestion and make another api request to get the details of that one game.

Comment: you can set a global object games for example then in for loop set games[data[id'].id] = data[i] then you can get the data set just by getting id